# Logical approach needed to solve this issue

Tags: logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I have data in the following format:

[As is state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62VSP.png)

Basically, the middle row falls under both the buckets (this year v/s last year), that needs to aggregated both ways, and I need data to be in the following format:

[to be state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRZEX.png)

Please note that I am not using any kind of programming language that would allow me access to loops etc. If you could just use flags and can aggregate data on the basis of those flags (weighted sums etc), how'd you approach this problem? I am interested more in the approach rather than real programmed solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Excel. In the final "sales" column use a `countifs()` formula to count the combinations of values from the initial table.